# How to arrange dock windows vertically in Qt LeftDock area?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt3

I want to put 2 dock windows in `LeftDock` area in Qt3. Since `LeftDock` is horizontal area, it adds new dock window to the right side of the current dock window. But I want to add the new dock window to the bottom of the current dock window which is in `LeftDock` area. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer. i should pass TRUE as a third parameter of the addDockWindow() function.

```
addDockWindow ( dockWindow, DockLeft, TRUE )
```